# Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =,.. or when the subquery is used as an expression

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I have this following stored procedure to make a reservation .I have not done the front end to insert the values so I use the execute stored procedure from the sql server menu to insert into the database but it gives me the `subquery returned more than 1 value and 1 row affected` message

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Usp_makereservation] 
  --roombookingdetails 
  @refno             VARCHAR(50), 
  @propertyid     int, 
  @roomtype          VARCHAR(3), 
  @groupcode         VARCHAR(30), 
  @companycode       VARCHAR(10), 
  @arrivaldate       DATETIME, 
  @arrivalplan       VARCHAR(3), 
  @departuredate     DATETIME, 
  @departureplan     VARCHAR(3), 
  @createdby         INT, 

  --roombookingguestdetails 
  @subsrno           VARCHAR(50), 
  @roomno            VARCHAR(30), 
  @guesttitle        VARCHAR(30), 
  @lname             VARCHAR(50), 
  @fname             VARCHAR(50), 
  @mname             VARCHAR(50), 
  @address           VARCHAR(100), 
  @city              VARCHAR(30), 
  @state             VARCHAR(30), 
  @country           INT, 
  @zipcode           VARCHAR(50), 
  @telno             VARCHAR(15), 
  @mobile            VARCHAR(15), 
  @fax               VARCHAR(50), 
  @gueststatus       INT, 
  @designation       VARCHAR(50), 
  @occupation        VARCHAR(50), 
  @arrivalfrom       VARCHAR(50), 
  @departureto       VARCHAR(50), 
  @leader            BIT, 
  @spclinstrctn      VARCHAR(1000), 
  @checkinflg        BIT, 

  --roombookingoccupancy 
  @singlebooked      INT, 
  @singleprovisional INT, 
  @singleconfirmed   INT, 
  @singlewaitlisted  INT, 
  @doublebooked      INT, 
  @doubleprovisional INT, 
  @doubleconfirmed   INT, 
  @doublewaitlisted  INT, 
  @triplebooked      INT, 
  @tripleprovisional INT, 
  @tripleconfirmed   INT, 
  @triplewaitlisted  INT, 
  @quadbooked        INT, 
  @quadprovisional   INT, 
  @quadconfirmed     INT, 
  @quadwaitlisted    INT, 
  @marketsegID       INT, 
  @businesssrcID     INT, 
  @guestcategoryID   INT, 
  @gueststatusID     INT, 
  @totalpax          INT, 
  @adultpax          INT, 
  @childpax          INT, 
  @infantpax         INT, 
  @extraadultpax     INT, 
  @extrachildpax     INT, 
  @complementarypax  INT, 
  @noshow            INT, 
  @checkinrooms      INT, 
  @checkinpax        INT 
AS 
  BEGIN 
      BEGIN try 
          BEGIN TRAN 

          INSERT INTO roombookingdetails 
                      (reservationno, 
                       srno, 
                       refno, 
                       propertyid, 
                       roomtype, 
                       groupcode, 
                       companycode, 
                       arrivaldate, 
                       arrivalplan, 
                       depaturedate, 
                       depatureplan, 
                       createdon, 
                       createdby) 
          VALUES      ((SELECT Isnull(Max(reservationno) + 1, 1) 
                        FROM   roombookingdetails), 
                       (SELECT Isnull(Max(srno) + 1, 1) 
                        FROM   roombookingdetails), 
                       @refno, 
                       @propertyid, 
                       @roomtype, 
                       @groupcode, 
                       @companycode, 
                       @arrivaldate, 
                       @arrivalplan, 
                       @departuredate, 
                       @departureplan, 
                       Getdate(), 
                       @createdby) 

          INSERT INTO roombookingguestdetails 
                      (reservationno, 
                       srno, 
                       subsrno, 
                       roomno, 
                       guesttitle, 
                       lastname, 
                       firstname, 
                       midname, 
                       [address], 
                       city, 
                       [state], 
                       country, 
                       zipcode, 
                       telno, 
                       mobile, 
                       fax, 
                       gueststatus, 
                       designation, 
                       occupation, 
                       arrivalfrom, 
                       depatureto, 
                       leader, 
                       specialinstruction, 
                       checkinflag, 
                       createdon, 
                       createdby) 
          VALUES      ((SELECT [reservationno] 
                        FROM   roombookingdetails), 
                       (SELECT Isnull(Max(srno) + 1, 1) 
                        FROM   roombookingguestdetails), 
                       @subsrno, 
                       @roomno, 
                       @guesttitle, 
                       @lname, 
                       @fname, 
                       @mname, 
                       @address, 
                       @city, 
                       @state, 
                       @country, 
                       @zipcode, 
                       @telno, 
                       @mobile, 
                       @fax, 
                       @gueststatus, 
                       @designation, 
                       @occupation, 
                       @arrivalfrom, 
                       @departureto, 
                       @leader, 
                       @spclinstrctn, 
                       @checkinflg, 
                       Getdate(), 
                       @createdby) 

          INSERT INTO roombookingoccupancy 
                      (reservationno, 
                       srno, 
                       singlebooked, 
                       singleprovisional, 
                       singleconfirmed, 
                       singlewaitlisted, 
                       doublebooked, 
                       doubleprovisional, 
                       doubleconfirmed, 
                       doublewaitlisted, 
                       tripplebooked, 
                       trippleprovisional, 
                       trippleconfirmed, 
                       tripplewaitlisted, 
                       quadbooked, 
                       quadprovisional, 
                       quadconfirmed, 
                       quadwaitlisted, 
                       marketsegmentid, 
                       businesssourceid, 
                       guestcategoryid, 
                       gueststatusid, 
                       totalpax, 
                       adultpax, 
                       childpax, 
                       infantpax, 
                       extraadultpax, 
                       extrachildpax, 
                       complementrypax, 
                       noshow, 
                       checkinrooms, 
                       checkinpax, 
                       createdon, 
                       createdby) 
          VALUES      ((SELECT [reservationno] 
                        FROM   roombookingdetails), 
                       (SELECT Isnull(Max(srno) + 1, 1) 
                        FROM   roombookingoccupancy), 
                       @singlebooked, 
                       @singleprovisional, 
                       @singleconfirmed, 
                       @singlewaitlisted, 
                       @doublebooked, 
                       @doubleprovisional, 
                       @doubleconfirmed, 
                       @doublewaitlisted, 
                       @triplebooked, 
                       @tripleprovisional, 
                       @tripleconfirmed, 
                       @triplewaitlisted, 
                       @quadbooked, 
                       @quadprovisional, 
                       @quadconfirmed, 
                       @quadwaitlisted, 
                       @marketsegID, 
                       @businesssrcID, 
                       @guestcategoryID, 
                       @gueststatusID, 
                       @totalpax, 
                       @adultpax, 
                       @childpax, 
                       @infantpax, 
                       @extraadultpax, 
                       @extrachildpax, 
                       @complementarypax, 
                       @noshow, 
                       @checkinrooms, 
                       @checkinpax, 
                       Getdate(), 
                       @createdby) 

          COMMIT TRAN 
      END try 

      BEGIN catch 
          PRINT 'Rollback' 
            SELECT ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber, ERROR_SEVERITY() AS ErrorSeverity, ERROR_STATE() AS ErrorState, ERROR_PROCEDURE() AS ErrorProcedure, ERROR_LINE() AS ErrorLine, ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage;

          ROLLBACK 
      END catch 
  END
```

Here is the query generated after selecting `execute stored procedure` command

```
DECLARE @return_value int

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[Usp_makereservation]
        @refno = N'12',
        @propertyid = 2,
        @roomtype = N'R345',
        @groupcode = N'G25',
        @companycode = N'C422',
        @arrivaldate = N'1/2/3',
        @arrivalplan = N'fd',
        @departuredate = N'5/2/3',
        @departureplan = N'gdfgd',
        @createdby = 1,
        @subsrno = N'g',
        @roomno = N'fgd',
        @guesttitle = N'fdf',
        @lname = N'gdf',
        @fname = N'f',
        @mname = N'd',
        @address = N'dfg',
        @city = N'fdg',
        @state = N'fd',
        @country = 3,
        @zipcode = N'rt',
        @telno = N'etr',
        @mobile = N'et',
        @fax = N'r',
        @gueststatus = 4,
        @designation = N'ertre',
        @occupation = N'tert',
        @arrivalfrom = N'ret',
        @departureto = N'ret',
        @leader = 1,
        @spclinstrctn = N'er',
        @checkinflg = 1,
        @singlebooked = 2,
        @singleprovisional = 2,
        @singleconfirmed = 3,
        @singlewaitlisted = 2,
        @doublebooked = 23,
        @doubleprovisional = 2,
        @doubleconfirmed = 3,
        @doublewaitlisted = 23,
        @triplebooked = 23,
        @tripleprovisional = 23,
        @tripleconfirmed = 23,
        @triplewaitlisted = 23,
        @quadbooked = 2,
        @quadprovisional = 3,
        @quadconfirmed = 24,
        @quadwaitlisted = 23,
        @marketsegID = 432,
        @businesssrcID = 4,
        @guestcategoryID = 234,
        @gueststatusID = 234,
        @totalpax = 234,
        @adultpax = 23,
        @childpax = 4,
        @infantpax = 234,
        @extraadultpax = 23,
        @extrachildpax = 4234,
        @complementarypax = 23,
        @noshow = 4,
        @checkinrooms = 234,
        @checkinpax = 43232

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value

GO
```

Comment: Subquery  `(SELECT [reservationno] FROM   roombookingdetails)` probably returns more then 1 row and should be replaced with some aggregate operation like `MAX`, like you used in other subqueries

Comment: You have to use` where clause`,`Top operator','Min,Max,Avg' in your subquery when there is such type of  problem or more then 1 record

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Replacing this `(SELECT [reservationno] FROM roombookingdetails)` from first insert

with this 
 `(SELECT Isnull(Max(reservationno) + 1, 1)  FROM   roombookingguestdetails)`

and this  `(SELECT [reservationno]  FROM   roombookingdetails)` from second insert

with this `(SELECT Isnull(Max(reservationno) + 1, 1) FROM (RoomBookingOccupancy)`

solved my problem

Answer (score 1):

There is chanch that your following statement may returns more than single value.
Please check it.

```
> SELECT [reservationno]  FROM   roombookingdetails
```

You have used it in your insert statement.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use`where clause`,`Top operator`,`Min,Max,Avg` in your subquery when there is such type of problem or more then 1 record exist.